# Use dotPeek from within Visual Studio without ReSharper

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper, decompiling, dotpeek

[dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) is a free .NET decompiler. While being a standalone tool, it is also part of [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/): If you tell ReSharper to navigate to the definition of a `class` which is located in a .dll file, it will automatically decompile the file and present you the source code.

I don't want to use ReSharper. Can I get the same or a similar functionality without ReSharper or is this a ReSharper-only feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `dotPeek`, I haven't found a way of integrating it into Visual Studio, so that you can view the decompiled source of some code. There is an option to add `dotPeek` to the right-click menu in Windows Explorer, so you can click on a DLL file and open it in `dotPeek`, but it's not the same experience as inline within Visual Studio.

Apparently `ILSpy` does have an addin which hooks into Visual Studio, though I've not used that addin myself. `ILSpy` is a fantastic alternative.

Comment: Just installed the `ILSpy` extension in VS 2019. It seems to work well and the ability to right click on a method name and inspect in ILSpy is very useful. It did take a minute for the context menu item to appear... possibly it was fetching debug assemblies?

Answer (score 2):

From dotPeek 2019.3.2 at least, an option exists to integrate dotPeek to Visual Studio.

EDIT: I've looked into this option and, what it seems it only do, is that within dotPeek, it allows you to export a dll into a visual studio project. So this does not answer your question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Actually dotPeek integrates with Visual Studio, allowing one to see the decompiled code in the core .net library by pressing F12 (Ctrl+F12).

To achieve this, dotPeek must be configured as a symbol server.

The configuration required is shown in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7spm6C2j30